# Reoccurring events without year using DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am a junior programmer, just starting out.  I have been given a task determining whether events (that will be occurring over and over again every year) are currently happening.  The events are stored in a database with in the format Month/Day start date to Month/Day end date, but no year.  To make matters more complicated the events do not span the normally calendar year, they occur on a fiscal year between July 1 one year to June 30 the next year.  It seems it is there is no way to have a DateTime object without a year, and I really don’t want to take the approach using an arbitrary year, because I don’t think this will work out in the long run.  As I understand it this something new our project will be doing more and more, displaying information (or not displaying information) based on the month and day of the year.  Given the current date, and an event that I know the start date and end date in month/day format, how can I tell if the event is currently happening?  And remember this could span a change in calendar year.  What would be really great if I could build this functionality into a linq query so that I don’t even bother pulling the events I don’t care about from the database, but I will take what I can get to make it work.  The language we are using is C#.  Thanks

Sorry about the structure of my post, I have not used stack overflow much
The Data in the Database is structured somewhat like this:

```
StartDate    |  EndDate
-------------|----------
3/21         |  4/15
4/25         |  5/6
11/30        |  3/7
```

And yes it is stored as a varchar.

Comment: Do you *only* need to find out whether an event is currently occurring or not? Is the type just varchar in the database? (If you could have four `int` fields, StartMonth, StartDay, EndMonth, EndDay that would be better.)

Comment: Also, your current question is really hard to read as just a wall of text. It would be very helpful if you'd structure it to make it easier to read - as well as giving sample data etc.

Comment: Sorry about the structure of my post, I have not used stack overflow much
The Data in the Database is structured somewhat like this:

    StartDate  | EndDate
    3/21      | 4/15
    4/25      | 5/6
    11/30      |  3/7

And yes it is stored as a varchar.

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect that, as well as to make it more understandable. Are you able to change the database schema? It's hard to use data which is jammed together as text...

Comment: I suppose I could change the DB schema, as I am new I don’t do those kinds of things too much, but if I really understand why, I might be able to make it happen.

Comment: Are the events guaranteed to last less than 12 months?

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend that you refactor your database to be more amenable to querying - you don't want to be having to parse the string values for every row, on every query. Additionally, you can add an extra field to indicate that the event is cross-year, i.e. that the "start" is after the "end", as per your final example. So you'd have something like:

```
StartDay   StartMonth   EndDay  EndMonth  CrossYear
      21            3       15         4      False
      25            4        6         5      False
      30           11        7         3      True
```

At that point you can write a query *reasonably* easily. For example:

```
DateTime date = ...; // Wherever you get this from

var activeEvents = db.Events.Where
    (e =>
     // Regular case
     (e.CrossYear == false &&
      (date.Month > e.StartMonth || (date.Month == e.StartMonth && date.Day >= e.StartDay)) &&
      (date.Month < e.EndMonth || (date.Month == e.EndMonth && date.Day <= e.EndDay))) ||
     // Cross-year case, basically, just invert start and end... conditions
     (e.CrossYear == true &&
      (date.Month < e.StartMonth || (date.Month == e.StartMonth && date.Day <= e.StartDay)) &&
      (date.Month > e.EndMonth || (date.Month == e.EndMonth && date.Day >= e.EndDay))));
```

You could express the same result more *simply* by using multiplication to turn month/day into a single number, e.g.

```
int pseudoDayOfYear = date.Month * 100 + date.Day;
var activeEvents = db.Events.Where
    (e =>
     // Regular case
     (e.CrossYear == false &&
      pseudoDayOfYear >= e.StartMonth * 100 + e.StartDay &&
      pseudoDayOfYear <= e.EndMonth * 100 + e.EndDay) ||
     // Cross-year case
     (e.CrossYear == true &&
      pseudoDayOfYear <= e.StartMonth * 100 + e.StartDay &&
      pseudoDayOfYear >= e.EndMonth * 100 + e.EndDay));
```

This works because there are never any months with over 100 days in, but it's a bit ugly IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could fix the database structure, as many others are saying. That being said, you *are* a junior programmer, and you may not have much of a say in the matter.

#### Good news: you still have a few options.

A few things that I've noted from your question:

1. You apparently have an events table that contains partial date fragments, stored in varchar format. No year information is available.
2. You have a concept of a fiscal year, running from July 1 to June 30 - e.g. July 1, 2016 - June 30, 2017.
3. Based on the above 2 points, I believe that you are referring to a table that contains annually repeating events (i.e. each listed row item occurs once a year).
4. So now, to rephrase your question: given the **current date**, and **the above parameters**, how can you tell that an event is approaching, is happening right now, or has passed?

#### I think what you need to do is the following:

1. You need some programmatic structure to hold the event data in the table. So create a class that has a start date, end date, and an enum indicator to denote whether the event has passed, is occurring right now, or is approaching (in the future). You probably will want to store some kind of ID or description as well. Also probably makes sense to store these date fragments into the event object as well.
2. I think the event table rows are not going to be a huge set, so using some ORM like PetaPoco, Dapper, EF, etc, you should pull down the table rows into the class that you designed. You will probably need to establish some ORM mapping - you'll have to research how to do this.
3. Reconstruct the dates from the date fragments in the events table, by using the `DateTime.TryParse` method. Simply take the fragment, and add the **current** year to the fragment. So for your example `3/21` and `4/15`, you would extend those strings to become `3/21/2016` and `4/15/2016`.
4. Once you've parsed the datetime values into the event object, put down some code to validate the datetime information, so that they conform to the fiscal year information. You know that the FY runs July to June. So look at the month part of your start and end, and see if both land prior to July. If they do, that means the year part is for the next year (do an `AddYears(1)` to the start and end). If they both land after, then you know they are for the current year. Now the funky part is if the start and end cross over the FY boundaries. Example: May 1 start, July 1 end. Based on the FY rule, the year starts at July, so we are talking about a May 1, 2017 start and a July 1, 2017 end. You will need to just work out the logic, I hope you understand my point.
5. Once you've established the datetime validation, all that remains is to compare the start date to the current date - if the start date is lesser or equal to `DateTime.Today`, that means that the event is either **a)** started or has completed; **b)** if not, then the event is somewhere in the future. If case **b)** is true, then you have to evaluate the end date against `DateTime.Today`. If equal to or less, then the event has completed (or will complete today). If greater, then the event is still in progress.

Sorry for the super lengthy post, but I just wanted to give you a high-level overview of how your requirements can still be met, reasonably efficiently, without having to trigger a table redesign.

I'm often leery of redesigning an existing table for a few reasons. One of the main one is, that I may not know the complete map of project dependencies against that table. For instance, some production reports may be running against that table. Or an Excel plug-in might be querying that table and producing some output for a user somewhere. The bottom line is, if something looks fishy, before you press for a redesign, try to figure out why it was designed like that. Sometimes the rationale for the fishy design is compelling, sometimes it's just an isolated product of bad thinking (hence can be redesigned with minimal risk).